# Apache ProxyPass only if from a Subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, reverse-proxy

I have two servers, both running Apache.
Server 1 and 2 are on the same Public IP address.
Server 1 has a Network IP of **192.168.1.101**
Server 2 has a Network IP of **192.168.1.102**

example.com goes to Server 1. That is exactly what I want.
I would like for beta.example.com/* to go to Server 2, via an Apache Reverse Proxy.
However, I would like only beta.example.com/* to go to Server 2.

How would I configure Apache to proxy Server 2 only with the one subdomain?

Comment: Where does the request to port 80 on public ip forwarded to?

Comment: @Sachin - It is forwarded to 192.168.1.101

Comment: ok. Look at my answer below and try it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am assuming that request to public ip goes to server1. You can try this basic configuration on server1 using NameVirtualHost and `mod_proxy` module.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName beta.example.com
ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.102/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.102/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example
</VirtualHost>
```